# Driving a TC4428 using PC817

Tags: opto-isolator, mosfet-driver

I want to drive a mosfet using a `mosfet-driver` (TC4428). The frequency of turning on-off of mosfet is 5-10 Hz (yes Hz) and duty cycle is 10-20%. I use PC817 as below to make isolation:
[image]

As you see, if **FLASH1 STROBE** be 4.8 volts, voltage of `collector` will be 0.18 volt. **FLASH1 STROBE** comes from a ATMEGA16 port. Is there any problem with this design? I mean 0.18 volt on collector and 4.8 volt on **FLASH1 STROBE**.

Comment: What is the PC817's Vcc? 5v?  What is the TC4428's Vcc?  12v?

Comment: There is no Vcc pin for PC817. The Vdd for TC4428 is 9 volts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems normally optoisolators in this setup:
 - Rise times
 - Not a low enough V_IL for the gate driver

Rise times aren't going to be a problem at 5 to 10Hz. The V_IL is 0.8V for the TC4426 so if the optoisolator pulls down to 0.2V you should be fine.

Comment: Is there any to make 0.2 V be less? I'm worry about that noises make it more than this value (and it reaches ~0.8 V).

Comment: I think your fine, you have 0.6V of headroom, that should be enough. If your getting ground noise or Vcc noise larger than 0.1V then you'll have many other problems.